# PHP and HTML pagination

Tags: php, html

I have the following pagination from 1 to 10 page. I will have over 50 pages. This is the URL: `http://www.example.com/page?page1`.

What I want to do is:

```
if(isset($_GET['page10'])){
```

change **THIS** code

```
<li class="page-item<?if(isset($_GET['page1'])){echo $active;}?>"><a href="#" class="page-link" title="page1">1</a></li>
<li class="page-item<?if(isset($_GET['page2'])){echo $active;}?>"><a href="#" class="page-link" title="page2">2</a></li>
<li class="page-item<?if(isset($_GET['page3'])){echo $active;}?>"><a href="#" class="page-link" title="page3">3</a></li>
```

To **THIS** code

```
<li class="page-item<?if(isset($_GET['page11'])){echo $active;}?>"><a href="#" class="page-link" title="page11">11</a></li>
<li class="page-item<?if(isset($_GET['page12'])){echo $active;}?>"><a href="#" class="page-link" title="page12">12</a></li>
<li class="page-item<?if(isset($_GET['page13'])){echo $active;}?>"><a href="#" class="page-link" title="page13">13</a></li>
```

Any smart solution on how to do this?

I am new to PHP and I always run into some messy stuff when I try to combine HTML with PHP.

I was thinking about my "problem" and this code solve it but I know its little bit dangerous but if I use it only for Pagination it should be ok ?

```
        <?php
    $active = ' active';
    $queries = array('n' => null,);
    $query = array_unique($queries);
    parse_str(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],ENT_QUOTES), $queries);                    
 foreach ($query as $query => $val) { // xxx.xxx.xx/?$query=$val 
    if($query == 'p' && $val == 1 || $val == 2 || $val == 3 || $val == 4 || $val == 5){?>
  <li class="page-item"><a href="http://xx.xx.cz/page?p=1" class="page-link" aria-label="Previous" title="První stránka"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span></a></li>
  <li class="page-itemm<?php if($query == 'p' && $val == 1)echo $active; ?>"><a href="http://xx.xx.cz/page?p=1" class="page-link" title="page1">1</a></li>
  <li class="page-itemm<?php if($query == 'p' && $val == 2)echo $active; ?>"><a href="http://xx.xx.cz/page?p=2" class="page-link" title="page2">2</a></li>
   <li class="page-itemm<?php if($query == 'p' && $val == 3)echo $active; ?>"><a href="http://xx.xx.cz/page?p=3" class="page-link" title="page3">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-itemm<?php if($query == 'p' && $val == 4)echo $active; ?>"><a href="http://xxx.xx.cz/page?p=4" class="page-link" title="page4">4</a></li>
    <li class="page-itemm<?php if($query == 'p' && $val == 5)echo $active; ?>"><a href="http://xx.xx.cz/page?p=5" class="page-link" title="page5">5</a></li>
     <li class="page-item"><a href="http://xx.xx.cz/page?p=6" class="page-link" aria-label="Next" title="Další stránka"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a></li>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Take a look at the `_GET` Parameter: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php. Do it with `?page=1` or `?page=11`.

Comment: Maybe I could say if(isset($_GET['page10')){ include(DIR .'/xx.php');} but i dont wanna make more filles

Comment: Well basicly if you are in http://www.xxx.xx/page?page10 then you should see pagnation for next 10 pages so 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 atc

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this:

```
<?php $page=(isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:0); ?>
<li class="page-item<?php if($page==1)echo $active; ?>"><a href="#" class="page-link" title="page1">1</a></li>
```

Than you could look at the loop functions (for, foreach, while). In your case `for` ( http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php ). Take a look at the functions write your own idee for your problem and than ask again if there is an other question.

Comment: Be very careful using `$_GET` directly. Your site *will* start losing google ranking as soon as some spammer will find it. You should use `filter_input` method.

Comment: Can you provide me some example how to do with filter_input ? Or some library where I can read about it ? Thanks